Forward input value with same type
I'm trying to forward an input of a (external) component - this input is of type string | undefined.
But when i define my own input with the exact same type, i get an error that the types are incompatible
Type string | undefined is not assignable to type string | undefined
Type string | undefined is not assignable to type string
Type undefined is not assignable to type string 

Its works fine for my own component inputs and all inputs that doesn't allow undefined. Checked the source of the external component and the input definition is identical to my own - so i am not sure why it does behave differently and how to get it working without the exclamation mark
( all strict compiler options are enabled / true )

please share the minimal reproducible code
